# error when cloning repository with submodule, but submodule can be cloned in standalone

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules, ssh-keys, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a repository with a submodule in it. I've an error when cloning the submodule:

```sh
$ git clone git@my.server.ip:MainProject.git --recurse-submodules
Cloning into 'MainProject'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 28528, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13685/13685), done.
remote: Total 28528 (delta 22551), reused 19131 (delta 14714)
Receiving objects: 100% (28528/28528), 210.20 MiB | 1.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (22551/22551), done.
Updating files: 100% (1885/1885), done.
Submodule 'ThirdParty/Submodule' (git@my.server.ip:Submodule.git) registered for path 'ThirdParty/Submodule'
Cloning into 'H:/Projects/MainProject/ThirdParty/Submodule'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@my.server.ip: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@my.server.ip:Submodule.git' into submodule path 'H:/Projects/MainProject/ThirdParty/Submodule' failed
Failed to clone 'ThirdParty/Submodule'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'H:/Projects/MainProject/ThirdParty/Submodule'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@my.server.ip: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@my.server.ip:Submodule.git' into submodule path 'H:/Projects/MainProject/ThirdParty/Submodule' failed
Failed to clone 'ThirdParty/Submodule' a second time, aborting
```

If I try to clone directly the submodule repository, it works:

```sh
$ git clone git@my.server.ip:Submodule.git
Cloning into 'Submodule'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 1342, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1090/1090), done.
remote: Total 1342 (delta 782), reused 293 (delta 170)
Receiving objects: 100% (1342/1342), 167.59 MiB | 988.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (782/782), done.
```

What can be the problem? How can I fix it?

The repository is hosted with gitolite, and I've already verified that my key works for both main project and submodule (otherwise I should not be able to clone both of them, even if submodule problem in main project).

Comment: `git clone git@my.server.ip:Submodule.git` asks passphrase for the key. It seems it cannot ask when clonning the superproject. My advice is to use `ssh-agent` to hold the key without passphrase.